# iOS/Swift: directly manipulate remote MySQL over SSH

Tags: ios, mysql, ssh, swift3

is it possible to read, write, ... to/from a MySQL-database hosted on a remote server? I.e. can I connect to the database via SSH and directly make CRUD operations?

Is SSH possible/allowed in iOS, e.g. copying over images to a remote server etc.?

Comment: If this is for a publicly distributed app,  it would probably not be wise... someone could reverse engineer your credentials and then make global changes. (I don't assume you would want to give each copy of your app separate credentials.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework like NMSSH - see it [here on Github](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH).

Here is an usage example taken from a [project](https://github.com/cagnulein/HouseAlarm/blob/master/HouseAlarm/ViewController.swift) by cagnulein:

```
var host = "your-host.com"
var username = "user"
var password = "pass"
var session = NMSSHSession(host: host, andUsername: username)

session.connect()

if session.connected == true {
    session.authenticateByPassword(password)
    if session.authorized == true {
        NSLog("Authentication succeeded")
    }

    var error = NSErrorPointer()
    var response = session.channel.execute("ls", error: error)

    NSLog("List of my files %@", response)
}

session.disconnect()
```

---

**Swift 4 & latest NMSSH version**

```
do {
    let host = "example.com"
    let username = "user"
    let password = "pass"
    let session = NMSSHSession(host: host, andUsername: username)

    session?.connect()
    if session?.isConnected ?? false {
        session?.authenticate(byPassword: password)
        if session?.isAuthorized ?? false {
            print("Authentication succeeded")
        }
        let response = try session?.channel.execute("ls")
        print("List of my files:", response)
    }
    session?.disconnect()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: is MySQL possible here as well?

Comment: It gives you access to you ssh host and then run command on it. Not sure what you mean mySQL being possible.

Comment: but this would mean that I would have to parse the terminal output in iOS? What I need is getting e.g. all rows from a table - is this possible this way?

Comment: I really don't know. You should play with the framework and see what are the options.